# Dependency injection when instantiating a new class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am pretty new to C# and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get dependency injection to work when instantiating a new class.

I have an `Error` class that I use to store basic information about errors, warnings, etc when using Quartz to pass to the UI when something happens with the job. We also want to use the Serilog inside those errors to log in case something happens.

How would I use dependency injection with my `Error` class to use `ILogger` (*Serilog*) when creating a new `Error` class.

The `JobClass` that we use has DI with the `ILogger`. ( I don't know if this matters)

When I do

```
Error e = new Error();
```

it wants me to pass the `ILogger` as parameter.

Comment: Rather than _describing_ your code, it would be better to _show_ your code with a [mre].

Comment: What they said ^ about minimal example. That said, if it's just a stand alone class (not a controller), don't pass the ILogger. Get it from the DI container.

Comment: One of the biggest points of dependency injection is that you _shouldn't_ be manually instantiating class instances, either inject the dependency (typically via the constructor), or if you absolutely have to -- use the DI container to locate the dependency

Comment: You can see a variety of examples here, including a controller and a normal class that grabs the dependency from a service provider https://auth0.com/blog/dependency-injection-in-dotnet-core/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I do Error e = new Error(); it wants me to pass the ILogger as parameter.

Well, yeah, you're trying to call a constructor directly, it has to be correct C# code. Dependency injection is at the framework level, not the language level.

With that in mind, if you want to construct an object with DI, you have to ask your framework to construct it for you, with something similar to:

```
var error = services.GetRequiredService<IError>();
```

And have your error class implement that interface and register it as a transient dependency (ie, get a new one every call).

I want to stress however that you shouldn't be doing this, DI spreads virally for you. If you want one of these things created for you, simply add an `IError` parameter to your controller constructor and you'll get sent one on object creation to do whatever you want with it.